# Writing and Reading CustomValues takes too long in PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, metadata, pdfsharp

I have a c# method that writes a custom value for given pdf file. In order to write a custom value for a pdf, I am using PdfSharp 1.50.5147

The problem here is PdfReader.Open waits too long for the pdf belove :

https://www.mouser.com.tr/catalog/English/103/dload/pdf/mouser.pdf

```
 public bool WritePropertyToFile(string filePath, string extension, string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            document = PdfReader.Open(filePath);  //Here it lasts 2.5 minutes !!
            var properties = document.CustomValues.Elements;
            properties.SetString("/" + key, value);
            document.Save(filePath);
            document = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (document != null)
                document = null;

            throw;
        }
    }
```

My requirement is to write and read custom values in miliseconds for a given file. Although lots of pdf files' custom values can be written and read in miliseconds, some of the files such as this one may cause problems for me.

Do I need to open whole document for writing or reading a custom value? Is there a different technique for this? Do you have suggestion for this problem?

Comment: You cannot promise processing of arbitrary pdfs in milliseconds. But 2.5 minutes indeed appears to be too long for the given example.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no method to open, in this case, large pdf's quickly in PdfSharp due to the fact that PdfSharp first loads the entire pdf in memory. The pdf you're trying to open is a whopping 168MB file.

You may extend PdfSharp and try to load the trailer contents first and then read each block of contents according to trailer entries.